# Fetching redirect after post method python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch the redirected URL after I post.

```
import requests
import cfscrape


# Our session so it doesn't reset after each post request, we need the scraper cuz of cloudflare
session = requests.session()
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=session)

# Login url and our post payload.
login_url = "https://osbot.org/forum/login/"
login_payload = {'auth': f'{self.username}',
                 'password': f'{self.password}'}

scraper.post(url=login_url, data=login_payload)
```

How the post data looks like if you do it manually:

```
csrfKey=8b0a2ebf49c323bd18af0aaea691138b
auth=username123
password=password123
remember_me=1
_processLogin=usernamepassword
_processLogin=usernamepassword
```

I expected to be logged in but there's a redirect after you log in but for some reason, it doesn't work on this. When I login myself to see the post data etc, I get a `301` status code (moved permanently) but when I do it via post requests I get a `200` status code.

Comment: Try with `scraper.post(url=login_url, data=login_payload, follow_redirects=True)`